# ODBC Error Drivers error '80004005' with 32bit applications enabled

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, iis-10

I'm trying to follow along with my school project, and I set up IIS exactly as they recommended, including allowing 32 bit applications. However, despite trying this on 2 different computers from scratch it still doesn't work. I get the error message:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>
> /LEGO STORE/Program.asp, line 17

My code is as follows:

```
<%
        dim con, rs, sql
        Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        con.open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("Lego.accdb"))

        sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1"

        rs.Open sql, con
        %>
```

I have no idea why it's not working, and I can't continue with my project until it is fixed. The files are hosted from my computer, rather than using a separate server. I checked the existing solutions, but they were for a different version of IIS and I don't know how different they are.

Comment: That 8004 message does indeed suggest a bit size miss-match. I would consider installing the x64 drivers for Access on that same machine with the web server. While you enabled x32 applications, your in process code is still likely running as x64. The other solution would be to install + run x32 IIS. Since you have a working setup, I would install access x64 drivers.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using IIS 7 or above, you'll also need to configure the app pool to allow 32 bit use:

1. Right click on the Application Pool and select “Advanced Settings…”
   or select the same from the Actions pane after selecting the
   Application pool
2. Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True and Click OK

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of database associated with the MS Access program, JET (.mdb files) and ACE (.accdb files).  The newer ACE format was introduced in 2007, long after Classic ASP had come to be regarded as "legacy", so pretty well any tutorial which deals with Classic ASP and Access will assume you're using a JET database.  The ADODB driver for JET, which ships with IIS enabled versions of Windows, is 32 bit only.  The ADODB driver for ACE is not included, you have to download and install it yourself.  It does have a 64 bit version, and as far as I know it *only* has a 64 bit version.

I suspect that the most painless way to achieve what you want to achieve is to open Access and save a version of your database in the older .mdb format.

OLEDB connection strings are generally prefered to ODBC ones.  In your case the connection string would be:

```
con.open("Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="&Server.MapPath("Lego.mdb"))
```

www.connectionstrings.com is a good resource, (as well as being a very easy url to remember).